# Count palindromic permutations ("mirrors") of an array

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I've been trying to find a solution for this question:

> Given an array of integers, count the distinct permutations that are palindromes ("mirrors"); that is, find the number of distinct ways that the array's elements can be rearranged so that they read the same way backward as forward. For example:
>
> 1. If the array is [1,1,2], then there is only one distinct palindromic permutation (namely [1,2,1]), so the desired result is 1.
> 2. If the array is [1,1,2,2], then there are two distinct palindromic permutations (namely [1,2,2,1] and [2,1,1,2]), so the desired result is 2.
> 3. If the array is [2,2,2,3,3], then there are two distinct palindromic permutations (namely [3,2,2,2,3] and [2,3,2,3,2]), so the desired result is 2.

I've been trying to solve this and been stuck for quite a while, and can't find any solution online. Any help will be appreciated (just starting out on algo & ds stuff)

My idea is to find the index of the median of that array (e.g., in example #1, the median is at index 1) and move all numbers after it to before it (so, [1,2,1]), and check using two pointers (one at end, one at start) if all numbers are equal.

However, this won't work if, let's say, #1 is `arr = [1,2,2]`, as doing the above would be equal to 1,2,2. What I should've done in this case is then to move the 1 in between the 2s (sort of median from the end, if that makes sense). Sort of like the above method but the reverse (?)

Comment: @trincot that's absolutely right. I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the general idea:

1. Count the frequency of each unique value.
2. If the array's length is odd, then exactly one frequency should be odd. If not, there are no mirrors. If so, that value will have to be placed in the center. The number of mirrors is then equal to what you would get for an array with one value less -- *that* value removed.
3. Now the array length is even. No frequencies should be odd, or else there are no mirrors. Now halve all those frequencies.
4. Determine how many permutations can be formed with those values and their (halved) frequencies. The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) is:

   ! / (<sub>1</sub>!<sub>2</sub>!<sub>3</sub>!...!)

   where  is the sum of all (halved) frequencies (i.e. half the size of the array), and the  is the list of (halved) frequencies.

Comment: Wow, you're an absolute legend! Thanks a lot. 

I have a question though: 

if my "halved set" is {1: 1, 4: 1}, value being the frequency, does n! (your answer #4) means (1+1)! ? 

Or is this wrong?

Comment: So for example [1, 4, 4, 1] has that frequency table. n = 2, so we have 2!/(1!.1!) = 2/1 = 2.

Comment: Yes, and we got the n = 2 from: **halved of frequency of 4** + **halved of frequency of 1** Is that right?          Also, the 1! there, is it just, again, **halved of frequency of 4** and **halved of frequency of  1**?

Comment: My question above is bc I don't quite get the your wording "...  is the list of halved frequencies". Thanks again though!

Comment: It is the **sum** of all  the halved frequencies, or equivalently, half of the length of the array. So yes, in the example it is 1+1, or 4/2, depending how you look at it. n is indeed half of the frequency of 4 plus half the frequency of 1.